# How to unsubscribe observable or subscription in RxJava2 ? or Do I really need to?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

How to unsubscribe observable or subscription in RxJava2 ? or Do I really need to ?

```
//Initialising Obersvable         
    Observable<SearchSuggestions> observable = NetworkContext.api.getSearch("");
        //subscribing obersvable on another thread and observing on main thread

            observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<SearchSuggestions>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(SearchSuggestions searchSuggestions) throws Exception {
    // here I receive the fetched results

                        }
                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
    //here the error
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscriber).

Answer (score 0):

to unSubscribe subscriber, maybe you should declare

```
private Subscription subscription;

//and use it :
subscription = observable.subscribeOn(..)...;
```

any time you want to unSubscribe just call, but i'll suggest to unSubscribe onDestroy (activity) or onDestroyView (fragment)

```
if (subscription != null && subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Comment: it is not there in rxJava2